# Convert number to asterisk

Tags: java, arrays

I'm new to programming and I'm creating a game that has two 6 sided dice and I want to use an asterisk to represent the percentage of the total rolls but I'm struggling with converting the number to print that number of asterisks.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class DiceGame

{
   public static void main (String[] args) 
{
  Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
  Random r = new Random();

  int numGames = 0;
  int[] die = new int[13];
  int rollOne = 0;
  int rollTwo = 0;
  int numAsterisks = 0;

  //Game intro
  System.out.println("Welcome to the dice throwing simulator! How many dice rolls would you like to simulate?");
  numGames = in.nextInt(); 

  for (int i = 0; i <= numGames; i++)
  {

     rollOne = r.nextInt(6)+1;
     rollTwo = r.nextInt(6)+1;

     die[rollOne + rollTwo]++;

  }//end for

  for (int i = 2; i < die.length; i++)
  {
     numAsterisks = 100 * die[i] / numGames;

     System.out.println(i + ": ");

        for (int x = 0; x < numAsterisks; x++) 
        {
           System.out.print("*");
        }

  }//end for

}//end main

}//end DiceGame`
```

Also when I run this the number prints after the asterisks like so:

`Welcome to the dice throwing simulator! How many dice rolls would you like to simulate?
1000
2: 
**3: 
*****4: 
**********5: 
***********6: 
**************7: 
*****************8: 
*************9: 
**********10: 
******11: 
*****12: 
**`

What is causing it to do this?

Comment: `System.out.println(i + ": ");` - this prints the number

Comment: Add an empty ```System.out.println("");``` after the loop with ```System.out.print("*");```

Comment: "struggling with converting the number to print that number of asterisks" - How so specifically? You seem to be doing fine. "the number prints after the asterisks" - this is because you do not print a newline after the asterisk string, but do print a newline after the number and a colon, which are presumably supposed to go as a heading to the row of asterisks.

Comment: @Andremoniy: No need for `""` - `println` can be nullary (`System.out.println()` suffices)

Comment: @Andremoniy I added the empty print line and that did help however it then printed an asterisk on a new line each time instead of being in a single row. Is there something else causing this?

Comment: @canijusttravel that's because it is inside the loop (so you get a newline after each asterisk). Put it after the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 for (int i = 2; i < die.length; i++) {
     numAsterisks = 100 * die[i] / numGames;
     System.out.print(i + ": "); //Changed println to print
     for (int x = 0; x < numAsterisks; x++) {
         System.out.print("*");
     }
     System.out.println(); //Added println
 }
```

The difference between `print` and `println` is that in case of the latter a line break is added. So you do not need a `println` when you print the number and colon, but you need an additional `println` after you printed all the stars.

Comment: Please explain the OP what you changed and how it helps, Do not post a code saying try this.

Comment: @Rab: Explanation added.Thanks for the guidance.

Answer (score 0):

I have done some changes to your method, first of all you do not need to Initialization the int values as they are already being assigned, and second I have added an instance to `System.out` and added the code to print empty line after the inner loop has ended thanks to user:  `Andremoniy` in the comments. here is the full code of it.

```
public class DiceGame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /**
         * Remove Initialization from ints because they are already being assigned
         */
        int numGames;
        int rollOne;
        int rollTwo;
        int numAsterisks;
        int[] die = new int[13];

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Direct call to System.out for making the code look cleaner
        PrintStream out = System.out;

        Random random = new Random();

        out.println("Welcome to the dice throwing simulator! How many dice rolls would you like to simulate?");

        numGames = in.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i <= numGames; i++) {
            rollOne = random.nextInt(6) + 1;
            rollTwo = random.nextInt(6) + 1;
            die[rollOne + rollTwo]++;
        }

        for (int i = 2; i < die.length; i++) {
            numAsterisks = 100 * die[i] / numGames;
            out.println(i + ": ");
            for (int x = 0; x < numAsterisks; x++) {
                out.print("*");
            }
            //Printing out an empty line once the loop has ended
            out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no need to define variables early. I think it's better to define them at/near the initialization. That also removes the "need" to initialize them with dummy values.